# Update Column existing values Order by a other column then the ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-update

I am quit new to SQL, I can't enter through the manager console the database.
I don't have the password, so I need to do everything with a Query.

In the database there is a Tag Position but this one is in the order of the Bundle Tag, This Tag position is used to create the Project Tree in the application.
And there we can' sort by project No. so all the project are disordered, so I need to update this column.
I found out this.

**1. First step to delete the values in the bun_tagposition**

```
UPDATE tew_bundle SET bun_tagposition = null
```

**2. Second step to insert the new value in the bun_tagposition**

```
SELECT DISTINCT bun_tag , bun_tagposition
FROM tew_bundle

DECLARE @id INT

SET @id = 0 

UPDATE tew_bundle 

SET @id = bun_tagposition = @id + 1
```

This code works fine, but the order is wrong this code have the order of bun_id
and I need the order of bun_tag which is the project No

Is there a way to fix that, to say to the code that it have to be updated follow the bun_tag.

Thanks for any help, I am suffering already some days on this problem.

Hugo

Comment: Which dbms? (The solution depends on it...)

Comment: In addition to adding an appropriate database tag, please edit your question with sample data and desired results.  This always helps clarify what a question is really asking.

Comment: @Gordon SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want a sequential ordering based on another column.  This suggests using `row_number()` and an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select tb.*,
             row_number() over (order by projectno) as seqnum
      from tew_bundle tb
     )
update toupdate
    set bun_tagposition = seqnum;
```